# Can anybody help me determine what this Cannondale is or is not?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, cannondale

26 frame. Red w/fade to purple paint. Labels; Cannondale F600 Headshok. Letters & #'s stamped bottom of frame as "FL" "11250" "00211" & "5F5W19" These are close guesses but guesses they are & as close as I can get to identify the writing. Believe it is 26" frame. Believe it is 21 speed Shimano "deoer" derailleur. "Rhynolite" rims? Sunrims? WTG Velociraptor 47/52 tires?

Comment: Pictures needed - clear and well lit from the right-hand side.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Cannondale F600 mountain bike, perhaps like this one

https://community.vintagecannondale.com/showcase/cannondale-f600-furio.1960/

Probably it's a 19" Large frame with 26" wheels. It would have been a really nice bike but is probably 15 years old or more now.

It seems like you already know what you have, for the most part.